# Emacs org-cite stuck in helm buffer

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Using Org-mode's new citation handling functionality org-cite (bundled as oc.el in Org 9.5+), I find myself stuck in the `org-cite-insert` minibuffer. It seems to be asking for an infinite amount of citations to insert, and my Helm minibuffer doesn't give me an exitable option.

Steps to reproduce

1. `M-x org-cite-insert`. This loads up the `HELM Org Cite Insert`  minibuffer.
2. Hit `Enter` on a citation from list.
3. I'm prompted to select another citation, but let's say I don't want to. It says `Key ("" to exit)` in the minibuffer, but I'm not able to select nothing, and writing `""` of course prompts the reply '[No match]'. Hitting `Tab` shows that there is only one possible action, '[f1] Sole action [Identity]'.

So basically it seems I'm stuck here unless I cancel myself out of `org-cite-insert` with`C-g`, and that `org-cite-insert` isn't playing well with Helm at this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Workaround :
after selecting all the entries hit **M-RET**. This should exit the helm org-cite interface and insert your selections.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thanks! Do you think I should file this as a bug to the org maintainers?

Comment: Yes. “Key ("" to exit)” prompt is really confusing. It should probably say “Key (“M-RET” to exit)”.

Comment: So there's a discussion taking place on the org email list. The command to exit is different for each narrowing framework, so it wouldn't make sense to hardcode only Helm's way to exit. Maybe something will go in the docs. If anyone out there is interested in the solution for Ivy, it's C-M-j. For Selectrum it's C-j.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting your first entry, call `ivy-immediate-done`. I have this bound to `C-M-S-j`.

Comment: That might work in ivy, but this is a helm buffer?